# Paperclip and carrierwave - file does not save + other issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have few issues about rails app I've made:
1. I've tried to use paperclip and carrierwave, but none of them save the file I want to attach to a specified folder. Attachment should be joined to user model:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @users = User.new
    end
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save 
            session[:user_id] = @user.id 
            redirect_to '/' 
        else 
            redirect_to '/signup' 
        end 
    end
    private
        def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :PESEL, :phone, :cv, :password)
        end
end
```

user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
        def new
            @users = User.new
        end
        def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save 
                session[:user_id] = @user.id 
                redirect_to '/' 
            else 
                redirect_to '/signup' 
            end 
        end
        private
            def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :PESEL, :phone, :cv, :password)
            end
    end
```

paperclip:

```
class AddAttachmentCvToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :cv
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :cv
  end
end
```

What is the task  - I want to have users 'joined' with the attachment, and then joined with jobapps model - so it will create new job app id, where the empoyee can decide if it is accepted or not. And I have a trouble with attaching a CV file.

Comment: Also  , I use mysql database

Comment: if you are using carrierwave then you would have create a uploader??

Comment: yes i have it and used but still does not work

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
storage :file
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end

Comment: So problem is solved
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288764/rails-paperclip-mysql-does-not-save-files