# rails paperclip mysql does not save files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The attachment resume seems to works fine, but i do not have any insert into database (null, null, null , null) and i do not have file uploaded to any folder in my app...

```
 class AddAttachmentCvToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :cv
    end
  end
end
```

User model :

```
attr_accessor :cv
validates_attachment :cv
has_attached_file :cv, :path=>":rails_root/storage/#{Rails.env}#{ENV['RAILS_TEST_NUMBER']}/."
```

I have also installed carrierwave but still no effects.. 
Edit:
User Controller (I do not have another controller for attachments) :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @users = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save 
            session[:user_id] = @user.id 
            current_user = @user.id

            redirect_to '/status' 
        else 
            redirect_to '/signup' 
        end 
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :PESEL, :phone, :password,:cv)
    end
end
```

View for new user with attachement:

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form">

    <h1>SIGN UP</h1>

    <%= form_for @users,:html=> {:multipart=>true}   do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
      <%= f.text_field :PESEL, :placeholder => "PESEL number" %>
      <%= f.phone_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone Number" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
      <p>CV</p>
      <%= f.file_field :cv, name: "CV", class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn-submit" %>
    <% end %>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some logs from console:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-18 03:55:17 +0200
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Fw6easThY51CDppDDVfqO0ProQITaltqP3DaIL3An67ey4vGXh2yEerhhhxoo3bTp/mKbkIaAmktzBviBIjg8g==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Test", "email"=>"test@t.pl", "PESEL"=>"91020300441", "phone"=>"609123123", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "CV"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f25790c1b60 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160518-26849-rqaabr.pdf>, @original_filename="pdf-test.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CV\"; filename=\"pdf-test.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'test@t.pl' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`PESEL` = BINARY '91020300441' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `PESEL`, `phone`, `password_digest`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test', 'Test', 'test@t.pl', '91020300441', '609123123', '$2a$10$HmHAiJkHv1Tada/OpzKXKOISiwumoFKTy48tFpNBYuATq/A5GaC9G', '2016-05-18 01:55:17', '2016-05-18 01:55:17')
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `job_apps` (`user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (35, '2016-05-18 01:55:17', '2016-05-18 01:55:17')
   (3.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/status
Completed 302 Found in 135ms (ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)


Started GET "/status" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-18 03:55:17 +0200
Processing by JobAppsController#index as HTML
```

Comment: Please show the controller code that handles the file upload, the view code that includes the file upload form, and the logs that show the upload happening.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill edited

Comment: So, just to be clear, you don't have any code on the server to receive or store the uploaded file?  Where is the INSERT that you mentioned that shows (null, null, null, null) for the attachment?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill in database, the columns for file are created, and all of them are null...and i dont have anything else (if u can explain me what is wrong i will be glad). And yes, the app does not create any inseert for file

Comment: Do you mean that the columns are created for the table, but that the table is empty?  NULL value for a column is not the same as an empty table.  How do you see (null, null, null, null)?  That's very specific to an SQL INSERT statement, which you don't have.  Please explain and clarify.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Okay, so I have NULL values in the columns that contains file information. Rest of columns have value which are inserted in form_for(first_name, last_name etc.). Sorry for misunderstandings

Comment: Where are the uploaded files supposed to be stored?  Local disk, database, Amazon S3, or some other location?  Which formats do you intend to accept as uploaded files (e.g. .doc, .docx, .pdf, .md, .odf, .tex, .svg, .wp, .wpf, .mp4, .mp3, etc)?  If someone uploads a 400GB file, do you care?  Since you haven't started the carrierwave implementation, there are a lot of design considerations left unspecified.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Okay, the thing is - I used paperclip to update just pdf or docx files. I have app on my system (using localhost) they supposed to be stored in path location (i tried also default path - nothing saved) and i didnt put any constraint on file size as nothing uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overridden the `name` attribute of the `file_field`, which has broken Rails naming conventions.  If you remove the `name` attribute, Rails will be able to pass the file details uploaded in the `:cv` field to the database.

Change the `file_field` to this:

```
<%= f.file_field :cv, class: 'form-control' %>
```

If you have Javascript attached to the form, and need to refer to the `file_field` element, you can use this, instead:

```
<%= f.file_field :cv, id: "cv", class: "form-control" %>
```